# # How to set head og: in Nuxt

Tags: seo, nuxt.js

I got a problem, related to the head on nuxt js. I have a news website, when I enter the details page, I head code like bellow.

```
head() {
            return {
                title: 'Rumaholi.com - ' + this.news.title,
                meta: [
                    { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: this.news.title },
                    { hid: 'og:title', property: 'og:title', content: this.news.title },
                    { hid: 'og:url', property: 'og:url', content: 'http://www.rumaholi.com/' + this.slug },
                    { hid: 'og:image', property: 'og:image', content: this.news.image },
                    { hid: 'og:description', property: 'og:description', content: this.news.title },
                    { property: 'og:type', content: 'article' },
                ],
            }
        },
```

when I test on facebook dev, apparently my head uses index

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rumaholi.com%2Fbuilder-as-bangun-motor-berlapis-emas-begini-penampakannya

```
head: {
    title: 'Rumaholi.com - Home',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { name: 'keywords', content: 'Oli, Oli Motor, Oli Mobil, Oil, Car Oil, Automotive, News, News Automotive, Berita, Berita Automotive, Berita Otomotif'},
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'Rumaholi.com - Berita  Automotive | Berita Automotive National | Berita Automotive International' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/icon_LnO_icon.ico' },
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href:
          'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons'
      }
    ]
  },
```

please help fix the issue